# imprimir resultado de una función alert en el documento

Tags: javascript, alert

Necesito que el resultado de alert se imprima donde dice resultado:

este es el html:

```
        <h3>Vamos a ver cuál de los 3 usuarios es el de mayor edad</h3> <br>
    
        <label for="edadPrimerUsuario">Edad Primer Usuario</label>
        <input type="number" id="edadPrimerUsuario"><br><br>
        <label for="edadSegundoUsuario">Edad Segundo Usuario</label>
        <input type="number" id="edadSegundoUsuario"><br><br>
        <label for="edadTercerUsuario">Edad Tercer Usuario</label>
        <input type="number" id="edadTercerUsuario"><br><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="cualUsuarioEsMayor();">¿Cuál es mayor?</button><br><br>
        <p>resultado: <span id="resultado2"></span></p>
```

*acá es donde debería salir impreso el resultado que también sale en el alert

```
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

y este el script:

```
    function cualUsuarioEsMayor() {
    
    let edadPrimerUsuario = document.getElementById('edadPrimerUsuario').value;
    let edadSegundoUsuario = document.getElementById('edadSegundoUsuario').value;
    let edadTercerUsuario = document.getElementById('edadTercerUsuario').value;
    
        if (edadPrimerUsuario > edadSegundoUsuario && edadPrimerUsuario > edadTercerUsuario) { 
        alert("El Primer Usuario es el mayor")     
        }
        else if (edadSegundoUsuario > edadPrimerUsuario && edadSegundoUsuario > edadTercerUsuario){
        alert(" El Segundo Usuario es el mayor")       
        }
        else if( edadTercerUsuario > edadPrimerUsuario && edadTercerUsuario > edadSegundoUsuario){
        alert("El Tercer Usuario es el mayor")
        }
    }
    
    document.getElementById("resultado2").innerText = cualUsuarioEsMayor.value;
```

//esta sería la parte que no puedo terminar de resolver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guarda en una variable el mensaje a mostrar en el alert para despues poder mostrarlo en el tu etiqueta SPAN

```
<html>
<body>
<h3>Vamos a ver cuál de los 3 usuarios es el de mayor edad</h3> <br>
    
        <label for="edadPrimerUsuario">Edad Primer Usuario</label>
        <input type="number" id="edadPrimerUsuario"><br><br>
        <label for="edadSegundoUsuario">Edad Segundo Usuario</label>
        <input type="number" id="edadSegundoUsuario"><br><br>
        <label for="edadTercerUsuario">Edad Tercer Usuario</label>
        <input type="number" id="edadTercerUsuario"><br><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="cualUsuarioEsMayor();">¿Cuál es mayor?</button><br><br>
        <p>resultado: <span id="resultado2"></span></p>
</body>
<script>
    function cualUsuarioEsMayor() {
    
    let edadPrimerUsuario = parseInt(document.getElementById('edadPrimerUsuario').value);
    let edadSegundoUsuario = parseInt(document.getElementById('edadSegundoUsuario').value);
    let edadTercerUsuario = parseInt(document.getElementById('edadTercerUsuario').value);
    var mensaje = "";
    
        if (edadPrimerUsuario > edadSegundoUsuario && edadPrimerUsuario > edadTercerUsuario) { 
            mensaje = "El Primer Usuario es el mayor";
            alert(mensaje);   
        }
        else if (edadSegundoUsuario > edadPrimerUsuario && edadSegundoUsuario > edadTercerUsuario){
            mensaje = "El Segundo Usuario es el mayor";
            alert(mensaje);       
        }
        else if( edadTercerUsuario > edadPrimerUsuario && edadTercerUsuario > edadSegundoUsuario){
            mensaje = "El Tercer Usuario es el mayor";
            alert(mensaje);
        }
       document.getElementById("resultado2").innerHTML = mensaje;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Mil gracias, Antoni!